# C# ASP.NET Checkboxes won't update in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox, webforms

Cant seem to connect my checkboxes from front end code to connect to my back end code. I want to update only my checkboxes in the database.

Here's the front end code from the SQL source and the end of the Listview

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"
 SelectCommand="SELECT Create_Project.ProjectID, Create_Project.ProjectName, Create_Project.ProjectStartDate, Create_Project.ProjectEndDate, Offers.OfferID, Offers.UserID, Offers.Accept, Offers.Decline 
                FROM Create_Project 
                INNER JOIN Offers ON Create_Project.ProjectID = Offers.ProjectID 
                WHERE (Offers.UserID = @UserID) 
                ORDER BY Create_Project.ProjectStartDate DESC">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="UserID" QueryStringField="searchID" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>


            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProjectID,OfferID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table runat="server" style="">
                        <tr>
                            <td>No data was returned.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ProjectIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ProjectNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ProjectStartDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectStartDate") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ProjectEndDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectEndDate") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="OfferIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OfferID") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="UserIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="AcceptCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Accept"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="DeclineCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Decline"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Save" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table runat="server">
                        <tr runat="server">
                            <td runat="server">
                                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                    <tr runat="server" style="">
                                        <th runat="server">ProjectID</th>
                                        <th runat="server">ProjectName</th>
                                        <th runat="server">ProjectStartDate</th>
                                        <th runat="server">ProjectEndDate</th>
                                        <th runat="server">OfferID</th>
                                        <th runat="server">UserID</th>
                                        <th runat="server">Accept</th>
                                        <th runat="server">Decline</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr runat="server">
                            <td runat="server" style=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

And the back End

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            {
                bool Accept = false;
                bool Decline = false;

                foreach (ListViewDataItem item in Listview1.Items)
                {
                    CheckBox findcheckbox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("AcceptCheckbox");

                    if (findcheckbox.Checked)
                    {
                        Accept = true;
                        Decline = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Accept = false;
                        Decline = true;
                    }
                }
                string selectString = "UPDATE Offers SET (Accept, Decline VALUES ('" + Accept + "', '" + Decline + "')";
                SqlCommand usersql = new SqlCommand(selectString, conn);
                usersql.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
                Response.Write("alert('You have made your decision');");
                Response.Write("document.location.href='Offers.aspx';");
                Response.Write("</script>");


            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your code into the question; don't post screencaps of text...

Comment: Sidenote: Don't ever concatenate strings used in queries, that will at some point make your system vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Use parameterized  queries instead.

Answer (score 1):

First you should consider use `SqlParameters` instead putting your arguments inside a string to query to avoid sql injection.

Second, `UPDATE` does not follow `INTO`, is just `UPDATE OFFERS SET ACCEPT = @YOURVALUE, DECLINE = @YOUROTHERVALUE` and you should consider use a `WHERE`clause, if not, it will update all your records.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **findcontrol** in this way

```
 CheckBox findcheckbox = (CheckBox)Listview1.FindControl("AcceptCheckbox");
```

Now while checking condition you need to use `findcheckbox`

```
if(findcheckbox.Checked)
{
//your code
}
```

**Edit1:**

Based on Inputs from the Comments Here is the Button_click code

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     try
     {


         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
         conn.Open();
         {
             bool Accept = false;
             bool Decline = false;
             foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
             {
                 CheckBox findcheckbox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("AcceptCheckbox");

                 if (findcheckbox.Checked)
                 {
                     Accept = true;
                     Decline = false;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Accept = false;
                     Decline = true;

                 }
             }
             string selectString = "UPDATE Offers SET (Accept, Decline VALUES ('" + Accept + "', '" + Decline + "')";
             SqlCommand usersql = new SqlCommand(selectString, conn);
             usersql.ExecuteNonQuery();
             Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
             Response.Write("alert('You have made your decision');");
             Response.Write("document.location.href='Offers.aspx';");
             Response.Write("</script>");


         }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
    }
```

Comment: @edgar links may die try to post code here so that users coming from Google find it useful in future !

Comment: Cant seem to find ListView1 in the c# but its definetly called Listview1

Comment: <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProjectID,OfferID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

Comment: Tried changing it to ItemTemplate, didn't work either

Comment: `foreach (ListViewDataItem item in Listview1.Items)
            {
 CheckBox findcheckbox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("AcceptCheckbox");
             }`

Comment: @marty try to use forreach and find checkbox

Comment: okay so its not underlining anything now, which is good I think, but still says there are build errors

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
                {

                    bool Accept = false;
                    bool Decline = false;

                    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in Listview1.Items) 
                    { 
                        CheckBox findcheckbox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("AcceptCheckbox"); 
                    }

Comment: and then underneath tha

Comment: string selectString = "UPDATE Offers SET (Accept, Decline VALUES ('" + Accept + "', '" + Decline + "')";
                    SqlCommand usersql = new SqlCommand(selectString, conn);
                    usersql.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
                    Response.Write("alert('You have made your decision');");
                    Response.Write("document.location.href='Offers.aspx';");
                    Response.Write("</script>");

Comment: Can you move this to chat? says i dont have enough rep yet, I'm new to c# so apologisies if I am slow

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. It said this to me

Comment: i am working on your wuery and will update my answer

Comment: @Marty you dont need `declinecheckbox` , these will be handled by alone accepted checkbox only and you can remove decline checkbox from the design also

Comment: I need it to update too though. Essentially, its an invite to join a project. I want it so that if he clicks accept it says true and decline says false. But also want to give them the opportunity to decline. If that doesnt make sense just say

Comment: @Marty single checkbox says that  you can keep the checkbox text like this **Do you want to accept Project**  and a checkbox, if he check means he accepted which internally he dont want to decline

Comment: Build error. Says the name Listview1 does not exist in the current context

Comment: also says its expects ')' at the end of the connection string

Comment: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].Connec‌​tionString);

Comment: @Marty try to use this   `SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());` and check what is the name of your listview ?

Comment: Managed to get the string thing working. Going to update my code in the question so maybe you can see something I cant

Comment: @Marty got it in design mode your id is `ListView1` but in codebehind its `Listview1` . **v**  is small in codebehind that is the error i guess!!

Comment: Haha such a small thing, okay so now it builds, I click on the accept checkbox but it breaks on this line usersql.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: says this above it: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: and this Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: use `try catch` blocks please

Comment: Where and what is that? Never seen it before

Comment: check richardt answer

Comment: At the minute it is this "UPDATE Offers SET (Accept, Decline VALUES ('" + Accept + "', '" + Decline + "')"; Do I update it to "UPDATE Offers WHERE Accept=@Accept AND Decline=@Decline";

Comment: just for time being remove `@` when you got it working try using that way and carefull while concatinating and im leaving.. if its sovles dont forget to accept